# I upgraded to Ubuntu Bionic on our server but it asks me to upgrade to Xenial?

Tags: apt, server, upgrade

This is when I login via SSH (no console - remote), this is *Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic*. I have rebooted many times, I did `do-release-upgrade`, and it says I should upgrade to *Xenial*? How come? 2-3 years ago, I upgraded from *14.04* to *16.04*, then from *16.04* to *18.04*, so now, I am on *18.04*, and then it still says I should upgrade to *Xenial* as `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial`

My output is like this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue May  8 16:31:20 CEST 2018

  System load:                    0.0
  Usage of /:                     42.8% of 109.88GB
  Memory usage:                   39%
  Swap usage:                     1%
  Processes:                      264
  Users logged in:                0
  IP address for br0:             a.b.c.d
  IP address for br-123456789012: 1.2.3.4
  IP address for br-123456789012: 1.2.3.4
  IP address for dockerZ:         1.2.3.4

 * Meltdown, Spectre and Ubuntu: What are the attack vectors,
   how the fixes work, and everything else you need to know
   - https://ubu.one/u2Know

 * Canonical Livepatch is enabled.
   - All available patches applied.

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


You have packages from the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) installed that
are going out of support on 2016-08-04.

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade 

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial

and reboot your system.
```

How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script to detect HWE support seems to get confused with leftover kernel packages.

You can run "hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported" as root to determine which leftover packages are present in your system, then run "apt --purge remove" on each package to get rid of them.

After that you should no longer see this message.