# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 stucked with `Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success`

Tags: upgrade, desktop-environments, 20.04

I'm currently stuck in the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 and can't move on.

1. Text: `An upgrade might not succeed. Do you want to continue anyway?`
2. I press `[y]es`
3. `Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. […] To continue please press [ENTER]`
4. I press `[ENTER]`
5. Error "`appstreamcli: symbol lookup error: appstreamcli: undefined symbol: AS_APPSTREAM_METADATA_PATHS`" appears a few times between "`Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease`" and "`Hit http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease`". This follows:

```
E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if
/usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli;
then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi', E:Sub-process
returned an error code

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Thu Apr 30 11:54:41 2020) ===
```

Now if I press `[r]` ("to resurrect window") the loop begins again.

[image: screen record of upgrade loop]

**PS:** There also seem to be [the official issue 1873713](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1873713#yui_3_10_3_1_1588243784312_1429) but it seems that there isn't any documented solution, yet.

**PPS:** I'm also wondering about seeing `While scanning your repository information no entry about eoan could be found.` during this upgrade loop. Because *Eoan* Ermine seem to be 19.10 whereas I was updating from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. Which itself looks like [`ubuntu-release-upgrader` bug 1851040](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1851040).

Comment: I think I just found a workaround by commenting `if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info …` out in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream`. The installation is now continuing so I guess this output would be too late now? The _current_ output is `AppStream cache update completed successfully.`.

Comment: Now it got worse: as mentioned before it continued upgrading but suddenly the sign in screen (gdm) popped up but it don't let me signing in. It accepts the credentials, turns black and them I'm in the sign in screen again. The upgrade was started via terminal emulator (Sakura) and is now stuck. But I cannot access the GUI. What a mess.

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade`. Nice! It seems that the process was started within a screen session and I was able to attach it from TTY!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107404/discussion-between-user-dz-and-alexanderadam).

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I don't have any important things in `/etc` (I might have some in `.config` but I have backups of `.config`). How should I terminate the running upgrade process (it's in a loop again)? `ctrl + c`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I commented out `if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info …` in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream`.

Afterwards GDM showed up and didn't let me sign in (although I'm using lightdm).
I was able to complete the installation although I got stuck a second time and had to kill the update process. I'm sure it would have been better if I would have used

```bsh
sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive
```

instead (note the `DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive` option!). It's an advice from @user.dz but you should only do it if you can accept that `/etc` and `~/.config` will be overriden.

Also if you are running into this bug:

Check

```
sudo appstreamcli refresh-cache
```

(Also an advice from @user.dz)

Comment: After commenting out the line in `50appstream`, I was able to run `apt-get update` and `apt-get safe-upgrade`, and was able to let it overwrite `50appstream` file with the updated defaults, without running into the problem again afterward.